# Como criar um objeto do tipo Canvas no Lazarus e adicionar a um PaintBox?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Em um *Form* tenho um **Paintbox** com propriedade *Align = alClient* e um **Button**.

Preciso desenhar um objeto do tipo **Canvas** dentro do **Paintbox** no evento *OnCLick* do **Button**.
Este é o objeto do tipo **Canvas** que deverá ser criado:

```
const IconSize:Integer = 10
type
  Icon = Class   
  public
    posX, posY:Integer;
    constructor Create(X,Y:Integer);
    destructor Destroy;
    procedure SetX(AValue: Integer);
    procedure SetY(AValue: Integer);
  published
    property LocationX : Integer read posX write SetX;
    property LocationY : Integer read posY write SetY;
end;     
var CanvasIcon: Icon;
```

Este é o método *constructor* do objeto:

```
constructor Icon.Create(X, Y: Integer);
var Bitmap:TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap:=TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.Height := IconSize;
    Bitmap.Width := IconSize;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Rectangle(Round(X-(IconSize/2)), Round(Y-(IconSize/2)),
      Round(X+(IconSize/2)), Round(Y+(IconSize/2)));
    PaintBox.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Bitmap);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

E este é o evento *OnClick* do **Button**:

```
procedure TFormPaintBox.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CanvasIcon:=Icon.Create(10,10);
end;
```

Porém, o Lazarus exibe a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> src/unitpaintbox.pas(121,33) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "Create"

Mas o *constructor* recebe dois parâmetros, exatamente como foi especificado no evento *onClick* do **Button**. Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Problema resolvido da seguinte forma: editando o `Icon` por `CustomIcon`, e removendo as entradas do `constructor Create;`

Answer (score -1):

O grupo: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=pt-BR#!forum/lazarus-br, possui uma comunidade ativa que pode lhe auxiliar

Comment: Além de que o problema já tenha sido solucionado pelo próprio autor da pergunta, a sua resposta não apresenta uma solução com uma qualidade adequada. Apenas incluir um link não ajuda. É o mesmo que eu utilizar a seguinte resposta pra tudo: "Busca no Google que tu encontra", concordas?

Comment: Me desculpe, só tentei contribuir. Espero melhorar da próxima.